# How does one pass keyword args with mypy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, mypy

Suppose:

```
def foo(biz: str = 'biz',baz: str = 'baz', *args:Any, **kwargs:Any)-> str:
   return biz + baz
```

And I use this like:

```
def bar(ness: str = 'ness', *args, **kwargs):
   return foo(biz=ness, *args, **kwargs)
```

> Note that this goal (specifying keywords and passing args + kwargs) shadowed some other misunderstanding on my part related to args: args, in python, can't be passed in after an arg with a default value (a keyword arg) has been set, as correctly pointed out below..

Then `mypy` version 0.812 throws an error like:

```
$: mypy --ignore-missing-imports --disallow-untyped-defs --disallow-incomplete-defs

foo/foo.py:6: error: "foo" gets multiple values for keyword argument "biz"
```

---

Is there a way around this problem in particular **without** making significant changes anywhere other than the return line below?

```
   return foo(biz=ness, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer I was looking for, in the end:

```
def bar(baz='ness', *args, **kwargs):
   return foo(*args, **dict(kwargs, baz=baz)

>>> bar()
bizness
```

Comment: It's worth noting _why_ this works. Unlike the return in the question (`return foo(biz=ness, *args, **kwargs)`), if `biz` already exists in `**kwargs` it is overwritten with the value of `ness` when `dict(kwargs, biz=ness)` is called. Therefore `biz` no longer needs passing in separately and it cannot be passed in twice.

Answer (score 2):

Despite the ordering in the call to `foo`, the values in `args` are assigned to the positional parameters before the keyword argument `biz` is considered. That means that that `bar`, which *could* be called with positional arguments, *could* have a value assigned to `biz` before `ness` is assigned to it.

That is to say, `mypy` is catching the following potential runtime error early:

```
>>> bar("1", "2")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in bar
TypeError: foo() got multiple values for argument 'biz'
```

The string `"1"` is assigned to `ness` and the string `"2"` becomes the first element of `args`. When `foo` is called, the elemnts of `args` are assigned to the positional parameters `biz` and `baz`; in this case only `biz` gets a value, namely `"2"`. Only then is the keyword argument `biz=ness` considered, at which point `biz` has already been accounted for.

Comment: @Chris: Why do you think that mypy should not report an error, when *runtime python behavior actually also fails with the same error*? That is, if I remove all type annotations, the issue stays the same - a call to `bar('1', '2')` will fail!

Comment: @JeanHominal Why is that in scope?

Comment: @Chris: My argument is that the python code above is *not* perfectly functional. It only works as long as `args` in `bar` is an empty tuple.

Comment: But reading your answer, I do not understand - which part of the code are you allowed/willing to change, and which are you not willing to change (at least not right now)?

Answer (score 2):

From your answer, I will assume that you want the linter to pass on the definition of `bar`, and that you are willing to make changes on the implementation / declaration of `bar` for that purpose.

For me, the root issue is that the implementation of `bar` is wrong - if `*args` is not empty, then the call `foo(biz=ness, *args, **kwargs)` will fail with exactly the error that is reported by mypy.

```
def foo(biz: str = 'biz',baz: str = 'baz', *args:Any, **kwargs:Any)-> str:
    return biz + baz

def bar_from_question(ness: str = 'ness', *args, **kwargs):
    return foo(biz=ness, *args, **kwargs)
```

```
>>> bar_from_question("1")
1baz
>>> bar_from_question("1", "2")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/jean/Projects/python/test-mypy/test.py", line 7, in bar_from_question
     return foo(biz=ness, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: foo() got multiple values for argument 'biz'
```

For me, you have three options:

1. Fix the call to `foo` by not passing `args` anymore. Such a change entails no loss in functionality, as having a non-empty `args` in `bar` raised a `TypeError` anyway. In that case, you could also remove `args` from the signature of `bar` (again, without losing functionality - you simply replace a `TypeError` triggered by the call to `foo` with a `TypeError` in the call to `bar`)

   ```py
   def bar_do_not_pass_args_to_foo(ness: str = 'ness', *args, **kwargs):
       return foo(biz=ness, **kwargs)

   def bar_remove_args_from_signature(ness: str = 'ness', **kwargs):
       return foo(biz=ness, **kwargs)
   ```
2. Fix the call to `foo` by passing `biz` as a positional argument instead of a named argument:

   ```py
   def bar_pass_biz_as_positional(ness: str = 'ness', *args, **kwargs):
       return foo(ness, *args, **kwargs)
   ```
3. Hiding the issue from mypy (as I understand from your answer)

   ```py
   def bar_hide_from_mypy(ness: str = 'ness', *args, **kwargs):
       kwargs['biz'] = ness
       return foo(*args, **kwargs)
   ```

   However, if the objective is to simply prevent mypy from reporting an error, there is syntax for that:

   ```py
   def bar_suppress_mypy(ness: str = 'ness', *args, **kwargs):
       return foo(biz=ness, *args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
   ```

Now, if I compare the results of each proposal in a runtime interpreter:

```
>>> bar_do_not_pass_args_to_foo("1")
'1baz'
>>> bar_do_not_pass_args_to_foo("1", "2")
'1baz'
>>> bar_remove_args_from_signature("1")
'1baz'
>>> bar_remove_args_from_signature("1", "2")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bar_remove_args_from_signature() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 were given
>>> bar_pass_biz_as_positional("1")
'1baz'
>>> bar_pass_biz_as_positional("1", "2")
'12'
>>> bar_hide_from_mypy("1")
'1baz'
>>> bar_hide_from_mypy("1", "2")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/jean/Projects/python/test-mypy/test.py", line 20, in bar_hide_from_mypy
    return foo(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: foo() got multiple values for argument 'biz'
>>> bar_suppress_mypy("1")
'1baz'
>>> bar_suppress_mypy("1", "2")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/jean/Projects/python/test-mypy/test.py", line 23, in bar_suppress_mypy
    return foo(biz=ness, *args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
TypeError: foo() got multiple values for argument 'biz'
```

You can see that:

- for every case where `bar_from_question` returns a result, every other `bar_...` implementation returns the same result;
- every implementation except `bar_from_question` is silent on mypy, which I am under the impression is what you wanted;

In your situation, I would go for a solution to the underlying issue (that is, either applying bullet point 1, or 2), rather than just trying to coerce mypy (bullet point 3).